# After installing Yosemite, opening iPhoto brings my iMac to a halt

Tags: keyboard, imac, photos.app, macos

After installing Yosemite I attempted to open iPhoto on my 2008 iMac.

All my iMac does is show a white screen with a symbol of a file with a `?` inside it. I cannot use my keyboard either.

What happened and how can I make iPhoto work again?

Answer (score 1):

So everything was working fine, you opened iPhoto, and wham! ... a non-booting Mac? Something else has gone wrong here, and I doubt it's iPhoto. After installing Yosemite, did you do other things with it successfully, like browse the web, open a Word document?

From the screen you describe, the HD is the problem. Either it is completely dead, system files are missing/corrupted, a loose cable ... anything along those lines.

If you have a Time Machine backup of your HD, use [OS X Recovery](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) to recreate your startup disk.